# Unable to start the Phusion Passenger - Cannot change the directory - Operation not permitted (errno=1)

Tags: amazon-ec2, permissions, redhat, phusion-passenger, selinux

I'm running Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago) on Amazon EC2.

I have installed Phusion Passenger via a gem.

When I start `httpd` I have this error message in `less /var/log/httpd/error_log`

> [Tue Jan 21 08:07:43 2014] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd
>   running as context unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
>
> [Tue Jan 21 08:07:43 2014] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper:
>   /usr/sbin/suexec)
>
> [Tue Jan 21 08:07:43 2014] [error] *** Passenger could not be
>   initialized because of this error: Unable to start the Phusion
>   Passenger watchdog because it encountered the following error during
>   startup: Cannot change the directory
>   '/tmp/passenger.1.0.2072/generation-0/buffered_uploads' its UID to 48
>   and GID to 48: Operation not permitted (errno=1)

Output of `sestatus`

> SELinux status:                 enabled
>
> SELinuxfs mount:                /selinux
>
> Current mode:                   enforcing
>
> Mode from config file:          enforcing
>
> Policy version:                 24
>
> Policy from config file:        targeted

Content of `/var/log/audit/audit.log` related to `PassengerWatchd`

> type=AVC msg=audit(1390309663.196:134): avc:  denied  { sys_resource }
>   for  pid=2077 comm="PassengerWatchd" capability=24 
>   scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0
>   tcontext=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 tclass=capability
>   type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1390309663.196:134): arch=c000003e syscall=1
>   success=no exit=-13 a0=5 a1=7f0c303ad000 a2=6 a3=ffffffff items=0
>   ppid=2075 pid=2077 auid=500 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0
>   sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=4 comm="PassengerWatchd"
>   exe="/opt/walk-manager/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.26/buildout/agents/PassengerWatchdog"
>   subj=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 key=(null)

I'm new to SELinux so I don't know what other information I can provide here

I've made the installation of my entire project as `root` and as `root` I'm trying to start `httpd` the default user `ec2-user` doesn't have permission to start `httpd`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches:

1. disable SELinux
2. go through the SELinux audit log and add exceptions for the service. See [here](https://ask.puppetlabs.com/question/2100/passenger-selinux-issues/). Essentially you would need to use `audit2allow` to create the exceptions, restart HTTPD, find the next set of exceptions and repeat until you go them all.

Comment: The best way was disabling SELinux :)